# How do I come up with a formula to solve the following: If a cell is zero, add a number from a different cell to the total cost?

Tags: excel, vba, formula, cost-management

I need to add estimated costs and actual costs to a total budget.  To start, we put the estimated cost of travel on the spreadsheet.  When the person goes on travel, they invoice their actual travel costs when they return. We have to add the Room and A/V cost to both figures. So, when there is not travel cost invoiced (yet), I would like to count the estimated cost in the final total travel amount (amt. estimated (only if it has not been invoiced yet) + invoiced + the Room/AV Cost).

H8 Room/AV Cost

I8 Est Travel Cost

J8 Total Travel Est. (Room/AV +Travel Est.)

K8 Invoiced Travel Cost

Goal:  IF(K8 has a number, (then do not count I8) and instead add K8+H8)

I've gotten this far:

IF(K8<0*(J8), K8, J8)

Everything I come up with, Excel tells me that I'm asking too much.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=IF(K8>0,K8+H8,J8)
```

which states, "If K8>0 then K8 + H8 Else J8"

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head:

```
=IF(K8 <> ""; K8+H8; J8)
```

Also there is a Funktion ISBLANK which you. An use to test whether a cell is empty.

Comment: I'm getting this message with this formula, "There is a problem with this formula.  not trying to type a formula?  When the first character is equal(=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula: You type: =1+1, cell shows 2; to get around this, type an apostrophe (') first: You type: =1+1, cell shows: =1+1"  basically, this formula does not work for me.  Thank you anyway.

Comment: There was an encoding problem due to using my smartphones keyboard (wrong character for quotes). I fixed it. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the cells only can contain numbers. So this should work for you:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(K8);J8;K8+H8)
```

Comment: I'm getting this message with this formula, "There is a problem with this formula.  not trying to type a formula?  When the first character is equal(=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula: You type: =1+1, cell shows 2; to get around this, type an apostrophe (') first: You type: =1+1, cell shows: =1+1"  basically, this formula does not work for me.  Thank you for trying.